# Can an app be classified with multiple IAP types?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, appstore-approval

For example, having all these 3 models inside one app.

- Non-Consumable: Pay once to hide ads.
- Non-Renewable Subscription:
  Receive premium and personalized content for a set period of time.
- Consumable: Buy tokens to use in the app.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no restrictions (technical notes / review guidelines) that would prohibit you from using all three types of IAPs as long as you provide value to a user, who did not purchase anything. (e.g. your last example might not go through review)

> **4.2 Minimum Functionality**
>   Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App doesn't provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, or is just plain creepy, it may not be accepted. Apps that are simply a song or movie should be submitted to the iTunes store. Apps that are simply a book or game guide should be submitted to the iBooks Store.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality

I tried setting up the different IAPs in iTunes Connect, which is possible. The only limit you will find is a maximum of:

> [...] 10,000 in-app purchase products across all the apps in one account.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH3-SW10